# How do I "create an instance" in flash?

Tags: flash, flash-cs5, ads

I'm trying to display video ads in my flash player and I am completely new to flash. I am following this Google tutorial here: http://code.google.com/apis/ima/docs/sdks/googleflashas3_ads.html#load

Step 1 says to: "Import the relevant packages, create an AdsLoader instance, and add it to the stage."

What exactly does this mean? Do I go into my actions window and and copy and paste the importing code into my main code?

How do I "Add this instance to the stage"?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an instance meanse make a new "instance" of a class using the "new" keyword.
Like

```
var myLoader:AdsLoader = new AdsLoader();
```

and add it to the stage means:

```
addChild(myLoader);
```

And by the way, welcome to Flash development. Hope you have fun with it.